# JQuery treeview plugin cookie path

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins, treeview

How do I set the `cookie path` to `"/"` with the [jQuery treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/)?

Answer (score 1):

I just reset cookie. It does not need any patches for treeview plugin

```
$("#tree").treeview({
         persist: "cookie",
         toggle: function (args) {
             // get cookie
             cookieId = "MycookieId";
             data = $.cookie(cookieId);
             // remove cookie
             $.cookie(cookieId, null);
             // add with path
             $.cookie(cookieId, data, { path: "/" });
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I think its may be

```
$.cookie('key', 'value', { path : "/" } );
```

Should be easy to go , :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#red").treeview({
        animated: "fast",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true,
        persist: "cookie",

    });
});
```

It should be fine.

and this: jquery.cookie.js